# What does 直撃 mean in relation to an interview?

Tags: meaning

I'm currently translating [this interview](https://point-house.jp/article_detail.html/?id=11698) of a Japanese actor.

**直撃** was used for

> 猪野君に**直撃**

and

> 今回は“二択”で本音を**直撃**！

According to [Jisho](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%9B%B4%E6%92%83), it means a "direct hit".

The word seems to be associated with a disaster like a bomb or typhoon, based on [goo](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/145037/meaning/m0u/%E7%9B%B4%E6%92%83/).

However, I noticed that similar to this article, **直撃** was often used as a verb for a **headline** such as

[ゆき姐こと兵藤ゆきさんを直撃](http://english.cheerup.jp/article/355)

[スカイプ英会話「カフェトーク」を直撃](https://hapaeikaiwa.com/2016/02/07/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AB%E3%82%A4%E3%83%97%E8%8B%B1%E4%BC%9A%E8%A9%B1%E3%80%8C%E3%82%AB%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%80%8D%E3%82%92%E7%9B%B4%E6%92%83%EF%BC%81/)

I was wondering what does it mean and whether it was an abbreviation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

「直撃{ちょくげき}」 is a term often used by the media meaning "***(going) face-to-face***" as in interviewing a person in person instead of using telephone, email, etc.  You physically go to that person and ask questions.

This is why you will often encounter the term 「直撃インタビュー」.  Another common term is 「突撃{とつげき}インタビュー」, which literally means an "assault interview".

These terms are preferred by the media and audience alike because they sound "aggressive", spontaneous and quite catchy to the native ear.  It sounds as though the interview were conducted without an appointment even though most are obviously conducted on appointment.